# Coldfusion 9 CFIMAGE ICC Profiles - Not supported, why? & How to Resolve?

Tags: coldfusion, color-profile, color-management, cfimage

I'm running CF9 and just learned that CF9's CFIMAGE tag does not support ICC Profiles, which makes the "capability" pretty worthless on the Mac, which adds ICC Profiles to all screen grabs.

Has anyone else run into this. Is there a work around or solution to support ICC profiles? Telling the users images w/o ICC profiles are supported is going to leave many scratching their heads.

Comment: What is your question? How to extract ICC profile information or simply handle images that have ICC data?

Comment: You should add a feature request here: http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you might find what you need with 
[CFX_IMAGE / CFX_OPENIMAGE](http://www.kolumbus.fi/jukka.manner/) .. They're a free alternatives to cfimage, and they use ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick which support ICC. Failing that, you could always write your own tag in Java, as it's image libraries support ICC.